# javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

So , i've reinstall my OS, and now i have this exception:
     `javax.persistence.RollbackException`: Error while committing the transaction

My persistance.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="BookUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Entities.BooksEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

BookEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books", schema = "public", catalog = "postgres")
public class BooksEntity {
 private int id;
 private String title;
 private String description;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 public int getId() {
    return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 @Basic
 @Column(name = "title")
 public String getTitle() {
    return title;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
 }

 @Basic
 @Column(name = "description")
 public String getDescription() {
    return description;
 }

 public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
 }
}
```

Test:

```
public class test {
@Test
public void test_db(){
    BooksEntity book = new BooksEntity();
    book.setDescription("Well this fine now");
    book.setTitle("BOOOK");
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookUnit").createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(book);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
}
```

ErrorLog (cann't paste code normal) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/28xyvh2s3o0xr6v/Log.txt?dl=0

```
v 28, 2016 4:24:47 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: BookUnit
        ...]
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:48 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
        INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.4.Final}
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
        INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
        INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:48 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
        INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
        WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
        INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres]
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
        INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=admin, password=****}
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
        INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
        INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:49 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
        INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
        INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        Nov 28, 2016 4:24:49 PM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
        INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@194bcebf
        Hibernate: 
            insert 
                into
                        public.books
                                (description, title, id) 
    values
            (?, ?, ?)
Nov 28, 2016 4:24:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42501
Nov 28, 2016 4:24:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: permission denied for relation books
Nov 28, 2016 4:24:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Nov 28, 2016 4:24:50 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]

javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
    at test.test_db(test.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:56)
    ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2934)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3434)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1406)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    ... 28 more
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation books
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2453)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2153)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:286)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:432)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:358)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:171)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 45 more
```

I've searched this error, but solutions don't helped me. I guess problem caused by Permision denied ...

Comment: As described in the exception, you do not have the necessary rights to insert into the table.

Comment: Strange thing, with this login and password I can insert into the table with pgAdmin3 and IDEA db, but with java-code cann't...

Comment: Well, i fixed it, with changing role... nice.

Comment: Big thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the problem is: You have no permission for the table `books`

> `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation books`

And maybe next time do not show your password, even if it is on `localhost`

> `<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>`

Comment: Ok will check what happens wrong with permission .password for comfort, i just start to learn EE